# Postgresql: What is the best way to estimate " Select count(*)" for complex queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am trying to improve the performace of a select count(*) query which at the moment takes about 3.5 seconds to complete. The returned value is 363244.

I am looking for a way to either iprove the performace or to estimate the resulting value (estimation should be in the +/- 10% range).

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN products_locations pl 
  ON pl.product_id = p.id
  AND pl.height<= 4552
  AND pl.height>= 4543
  AND pl.width<= 7351
  AND pl.width>= 7344
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND p.id = ANY(
             SELECT product_id 
               FROM search 
             WHERE text &@* 'salt');
```

Explain analyse result of it is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=108878.17..108878.18 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=3632.017..3632.019 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104637.28..108876.96 rows=481 width=0) (actual time=529.865..3592.528 rows=363244 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=104636.85..108440.90 rows=481 width=16) (actual time=529.853..2111.177 rows=362887 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=104636.43..104641.24 rows=481 width=16) (actual time=529.831..668.965 rows=362887 loops=1)
                    Group Key: search.product_id
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 36881kB
                    ->  Index Scan using search_product_id_lang_text_idx on search  (cost=0.00..104635.23 rows=481 width=16) (actual time=54.861..317.960 rows=362887 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (text &@* 'salt'::text)
              ->  Index Only Scan using products_id_idx on products p  (cost=0.42..7.90 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=362887)
                    Index Cond: (id = search.product_id)
                    Heap Fetches: 362887
        ->  Index Only Scan using products_locations_project_id_h_w_idx on products_locations pl  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=362887)
              Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (height <= 4552) AND (height >= 4543) AND (width <= 7351::numeric) AND (width>= 7344::numeric))
              Heap Fetches: 9254
Planning Time: 1.646 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 16
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 3.865 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.451 ms, Emission 9.696 ms, Total 14.012 ms
Execution Time: 3638.721 ms
```

explain result of it is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=108878.17..108878.18 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104637.28..108876.96 rows=481 width=0)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=104636.85..108440.90 rows=481 width=16)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=104636.43..104641.24 rows=481 width=16)
                    Group Key: search.product_id
                    ->  Index Scan using search_product_id_lang_text_idx on search  (cost=0.00..104635.23 rows=481 width=16)
                          Index Cond: (text &@* 'salt'::text)
              ->  Index Only Scan using products_id_idx on products p  (cost=0.42..7.90 rows=1 width=16)
                    Index Cond: (id = search.product_id)
        ->  Index Only Scan using products_locations_project_id_h_w_idx on products_locations pl  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=16)
              Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (height <= 4552) AND (height >= 4543) AND (width <= 7351::numeric) AND (width >= 7344::numeric))
JIT:
  Functions: 11
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

If I could bring the count execution time, down to about 0.5 seconds, it will be perfect.

The DB containes about ~500k products ~ 550k search table entries and ~ 250k product locations.

Any idea how I can do it?

I already have indexes in place:
Products:

```
CREATE INDEX products_id_idx ON public.products USING btree (id);
```

Products_locations:

```
CREATE INDEX products_locations_id_idx ON public.products_locations USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX products_locations_height_idx ON public.products_locations USING btree (height);
CREATE INDEX products_locations_width_idx ON public.products_locations USING btree (width);
CREATE INDEX products_locations_product_id_idx ON public.products_locations USING btree (product_id);
CREATE INDEX products_locations_project_id_h_w_idx ON public.products_locations USING btree (product_id, height, width);
```

Search:

```
CREATE INDEX search_product_id_lang_text_idx ON public.search USING pgroonga (((product_id)::character varying), locale, text);
```

My DB instance is: PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

FROM groonga/pgroonga:2.4.7-debian-15

Results after vacuum:

```
Aggregate  (cost=108362.57..108362.58 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7268.687..7268.689 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104118.94..108361.37 rows=480 width=0) (actual time=725.183..7223.064 rows=363244 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=104118.51..107926.10 rows=480 width=16) (actual time=680.592..2646.080 rows=362887 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=104118.09..104122.89 rows=480 width=16) (actual time=680.530..846.736 rows=362887 loops=1)
                    Group Key: search.product_id
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 36881kB
                    ->  Index Scan using search_product_id_lang_text_idx on search  (cost=0.00..104116.89 rows=480 width=16) (actual time=77.920..377.805 rows=362887 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (text &@* 'salt'::text)
              ->  Index Only Scan using products_id_idx on products p  (cost=0.42..7.92 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=362887)
                    Index Cond: (id = search.product_id)
                    Heap Fetches: 362887
        ->  Index Only Scan using products_locations_project_id_h_w_idx on products_locations pl  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=362887)
              Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (height <= 4552) AND (height >= 4543) AND (width <= '7351'::numeric) AND (width >= '7344'::numeric))
              Heap Fetches: 9254
Planning Time: 39.116 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 16
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 26.384 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 26.962 ms, Emission 49.896 ms, Total 103.242 ms
Execution Time: 7300.211 ms
```

Results for EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT count(*)... with track_io_timing enabled:

```
Aggregate  (cost=108362.57..108362.58 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=9030.004..9030.007 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2513363 read=62175
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=4645.775
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104118.94..108361.37 rows=480 width=0) (actual time=773.642..8981.304 rows=363244 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=2513363 read=62175
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=4645.775
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=104118.51..107926.10 rows=480 width=16) (actual time=773.600..2851.648 rows=362887 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1438456 read=38071
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=326.060
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=104118.09..104122.89 rows=480 width=16) (actual time=773.542..944.752 rows=362887 loops=1)
                    Group Key: search.product_id
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 36881kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=24977
                    I/O Timings: shared/local read=206.245
                    ->  Index Scan using search_product_id_lang_text_idx on search  (cost=0.00..104116.89 rows=480 width=16) (actual time=56.756..537.866 rows=362887 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (text &@* 'salt'::text)
                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=24977
                          I/O Timings: shared/local read=206.245
              ->  Index Only Scan using products_id_idx on products p  (cost=0.42..7.92 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=362887)
                    Index Cond: (id = search.product_id)
                    Heap Fetches: 362887
                    Buffers: shared hit=1438454 read=13094
                    I/O Timings: shared/local read=119.815
        ->  Index Only Scan using products_locations_project_id_h_w_idx on products_locations pl  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=362887)
              Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (height <= 4552) AND (height >= 4543) AND (width <= 7351::numeric) AND (width >= 7344::numeric))
              Heap Fetches: 9254
              Buffers: shared hit=1074907 read=24104
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=4319.715
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=508 read=46
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=7.460
Planning Time: 66.997 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 16
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 3.342 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.640 ms, Emission 13.157 ms, Total 17.139 ms
Execution Time: 9124.662 ms
```

Comment: that is good that you have them in place, but how should we guees what those indexes are

Comment: @nbk I've added the indexes definitions in the description

Comment: that looks good, he uses inxex scan better you can't have it, and count are notorious for bad perfomance

Comment: Yeah I know about their bad performace. That is why I was asking about a way to estimate it.

Comment: Vacuum your tables to get rid of the Heap Fetches, then post the new plans.

Comment: There is no way to force the estimate to be within 10%.

Comment: @jjanes after vacuum all my tables, it got slower :). I've added the output at the bottom of the description

Comment: It is not good that it got slower, but I would still want to see the plans.  Do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) not just EXPLAIN ANALYZE, and turn on track_io_timing if it not already on.

Comment: @jjanes I've added the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) with track_io_timing=on, in the description

Comment: I've managed to drop the execution time to 1.6 seconds by rewriting the query this way:  SELECT count(*) 
FROM search s
LEFT JOIN products p on p.id = s.product_id 
LEFT JOIN products_locations pl ON pl.product_id = s.product_id AND pl.latitude <= 4552 AND pl.latitude >= 4543 AND pl.longitude <= 7351 AND pl.longitude >= 7344 
WHERE s.text &@* 'salt';

Comment: You still have very high heap fetches.  Maybe you have some snapshot being held onto in other sessions which prevent VACUUM from doing its job.

Comment: I've run the vacuum right after the postgres restart, with no other queries running on that instance.